# Embed WinForms in WPF used by PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I would like to embed WinForms in WPF used by PowerShell but cannot find good example.
Basically I would like to embed next in WPF:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("This is message","MessageBox","YesNo","Question")
```

I am getting error:

> Unexpected 'PROPERTYELEMENT' in parse rule 'NonemptyPropertyElement ::

I am not sure how to insert elements:

> ("This is message","MessageBox","YesNo","Question")

PowerShell code where I am trying to embed it :

```
Add-type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing,WindowsFormsIntegration

$ToolboxXml = @"
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
Title="Toolbox"
WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
SizeToContent="Width"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
Topmost="True"
Height="390"
FontFamily="Arial"
WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">

  <Grid Margin="7 0 7 7" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased">
    <WindowsFormsHost>
      <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <wf:MessageBox.show x:Name="MessageBox"/>
      </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
  </Grid>

</Window>
"@

$ToolboxGui = $ToolboxXml -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

#Load XAML

    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse(([string]$ToolboxGui))

[xml]$xaml = $ToolboxGui
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")  | ForEach-Object {  
    New-Variable  -Name $_.Name -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -Force  
}

#$MessageBox = $Form.Findname("MessageBox")

$async = $Form.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync({
    $Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
})
$async.Wait() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to use the WinForms implementation of a message box, given that WPF has its own, or is this just an example?

Comment: Kind a both, curious to see it working (if possible) learn something from it and also for transition period where I need to have some other project made in forms fuse to WPF project. Once time permits will transition to pure WPF.